# Sequential testing of elements in a 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, testing, iteration

Apologies if this is a simple question - I'm new to Python and numpy - but I'd be very grateful for your help.

I've got a 2D numpy array of data arranged in rows and columns, with the first column representing time, and subsequent columns showing values of different parameters at each point in time.

I want to read down a given column of data from top to bottom (i.e. time = 0 to time = number of rows), and test each element in that column in sequence to find the very first instance (and only the first instance) where the data values in that column meet given criteria.
This is different to testing 'all' or 'any' of the elements in a column 'all at once' by testing and iterating using the numpy arange() function.

As a minimal working example in pseudocode, if my array is:

```
myarray = 
[[1, 4 ....]
 [2, 3 ....]
 [3, 8 ....]
 [4, 9 ....]....]
```

...where the first column is time, and the second column contains the values of data collected at each time point.

I want to be able to iterate over the rows in sequence from top to bottom and test:

```
threshold = 5
for row = 0 to number of rows:
    if data in [column 1, row] > threshold:
        print "The first time point at which the data exceed the threshold is at time = 3 "
        break
```

What is the most Pythonic (i.e. efficient and intelligible) way of doing this?

Is it necessary to convert the array into a list before iterating & testing, or is it possible to sequentially iterate and test over the array directly?

Hope this makes some sort of sense...

Many thanks in anticipation

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
>>> myarray = [[1, 4 ],  [2, 3 ],  [3, 8 ], [4, 9 ]]
>>> stop = False
>>> for row in myarray:
        for d in row:
            if d > 5:
                print("Row: ", row, "Data: ", d)
                stop = True
                break
        if stop:
        break

('Row: ', [3, 8], 'Data: ', 8)
>>>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the quick & helpful response - much appreciated. So all I needed to do was use nested 'for' loops; then a 'stop' flag to break out of the nested loops...That all makes perfect sense ;-)